# Как плавно выдвинуть блок

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы при нажатии блок див выдвигался плавно, что нужно дописать?

Сам код (сперва стоит display none)

```
onClick="document.getElementById('cap_view').style.display =  'block'"
```

Comment: Если вы игнорируете jQuery, то для начала надо написать функции анимации. Но можно просто на css все сделать 

[по сути такой-же вопрос]http://hashcode.ru/questions/297280#297308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
    #block{position:absolute;top:0;left:20px;width:200px;height:100px;display:none;background:black}
    #toggle {position: absolute;top:150px;left:20px}
</style>
<div id="block"></div>
<button id="toggle">click me</button>
<script>
(function() {
    var block = document.getElementById('block'),
        block_height = parseInt(getCSS(block, 'height')),
        cur_block_height = 0,
        toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
    function getCSS(node, prop) {
        return getComputedStyle(node).getPropertyValue(prop);
    }
    toggle.onclick = function() {
        block.style.height = '0px';
        block.style.display = 'block';
        var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            ++ cur_block_height;
            block.style.height = cur_block_height + 'px';
            if (cur_block_height >= block_height) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 10);
    };
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите эту css-библиотеку, раздел captions http://h5bp.github.io/Effeckt.css/

Comment: ну и PageTransitions вроде тоже в тему
Page Transitions: http://h5bp.github.io/Effeckt.css/page-transitions.html
Captions: http://h5bp.github.io/Effeckt.css/captions.html